# vim doesn't recognize columns beyond 72 with fortran90 code

Tags: vim, fortran, fortran90

I am editing a fortran90 code with vim.  Note that I'm working with a *.f90 file, not *.f.  vim doesn't recognize as legitimate code anything beyond column 72.  This is an annoying problem because if a quote is opened at, say, column 50 but not closed until column 80, then vim colors all the following lines as part of the same quote.  This would make sense if I was working with an old fortran77 file, but I'm clearly not.  Is there any way to convince vim to recognize code beyond column 72?

Comment: Have you looked at fortran.vim and lines 65 to 78 associated with setting `textwidth` to 72?

Comment: @PatrickBacon   :set tw="whatever" doesn't change anything.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I wonder/suspect that vim is detecting that the file your editing is a fixed Fortran file where `b:fortran_fixed_source == 1`. What if you set `let b:fortran_fixed_source = 0`?

Comment: @PatrickBacon  I'm not too familiar with this stuff.  My exact command was ":let b:fortran_fixed_source=0"  No error, but it didn't change anything.  Did I do it right?  Thanks.

Comment: line 34 of the fortran.vim does not seem to be working for you (nor me). I think you could 1. exit the file 2. start a new vim session 3. invoke the ex command, `let b:fortran_fixed_source = 0` 4. re-open file.

Comment: @PatrickBacon  Thanks for all your efforts.  Most appreciated.  I tried your suggestion, still no change.

Comment: It works fine for me.  I'm using version 8.0.617.  What do you have?

Comment: Maybe you are trying to change a file in /etc/ but also have a local file in ~/.vim ?

Comment: @Jack I have 7.2.  This isn't my machine, so it will be updated ... when it is updated.  Think this is the prob?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if I create a new .f90 file syntax is highlighted as if it is fortran 77 (fixed line length, comments in first col, code at 6th col, etc etc) rather than modern free form fortran.

```
:let b:fortran_fixed_source=0
:set syntax=fortran
```

does the trick to get vim highlighting it correctly.

Comment: Thank you!  That did it!

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to the 'synmaxcol' variable. If you run

```
:set synmaxcol?
```

In vim's command line, what do you get back? Setting this option higher might fix your issue. It's generally set low as vim can get laggy when syntax highlighting very long lines, such as those found in XML.

Comment: Value returned is 3000!  Seems plenty big enough!  Thanks just the same.  Any other ideas greatly appreciated.